# Popover on hover, fill out from Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, spring, twitter-bootstrap

In my web, when hovering over a row, I show a popup table with data. 
What I want to be able to do is to get these data from the database. 
Currently it looks like this :

```
<td id="popupContent" data-trigger='hover' data-container="body"
                                data-toggle="popover"
                                data-content=" 
                                                                                             <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='sastable table-striped table-bordered' data-toggle='table' data-height='150' data-classes='table  table-striped table-bordered'>
                <thead id='head'>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='col-md-6'>Value</th>
                        <th class='col-md-6'>Score</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>0</td>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>10</td>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>20</td>
                        <td class='col-md-6'>3</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>"
                                data-html="true"></td>
                        </tr>
```

And the js function :

```
        $(function() {
        $('#popupContent')
                .popover({
                    container : 'body'
                });
    });
```

In my database I have a table like this :

Type   Value   Score

type1    0      1

type1    10     2

....

type2    0      1

based on the Id of the td I want to be able to call a certain type and all of the values and scores to put them on the popup table.

How do I achieve this ?

In a Spring Controller I have a RestController that returns a JSON file with the tables

```
@RequestMapping(path="/scores", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Scores> getAllScores(){
    return scoreService.getAllScores();
}
```

Maybe I could have a function like :

```
function getClientResults(type) {

// if type=="popupContent"
var url "/scores/"+type1 or something ?
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
  \\change table values ??
}
```

Am I on the right track ? or is there a better way to do this ? Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1** You will be injecting a php into top of your page where You will connect to your database and do a query to get the data and write it into that popup table like `<? echo $query['whatever']; ?>`.

**Way 2** You will create autonomus query page and when you hover the row it will send ajax request to that page receive data and will load it into the popup.